# MySQL where Clause not Working it Should Select active=0 but it Selects Everything

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this line to try to select the `active = 1` and the other line is `active=0`. The problem here is the two commands see the email of the session and not the active so it gets every thing the email has in the table.

```
    <body>
<h2>Wellcome <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></h2>
<h3>Manage Your tutorials</h3>

<div id="CollapsiblePanel1" class="CollapsiblePanel">
  <div class="CollapsiblePanelTab" tabindex="0">Tutorials add by you.</div>
  <div class="CollapsiblePanelContent">
  <?php
  if ((isset($_SESSION['log']) && $_SESSION['log']=1)) {
  $getUserData ="select * from tutorials where client_email='".$_SESSION['email']."' AND active=1";
  $getUserDataResulte = $db->query($userTutorialCounts) or die($db->error);

  while($tutRow = $getUserDataResulte->fetch_object()){
      ?>
      <ul style="list-style-type:circle;">
      <li style="margin-left:20px; font-size:14px; color:#006;"><?php echo $tutRow->tutorial_title; ?>&nbsp;
      (<a style="color:#F00;" href="index.php?learn_id=90&tutorial_id=<?php echo $tutRow->tutorial_id; ?>">Edit</a> 
      &nbsp;- <a style="color:#F00;" href="index.php?learn_id=5&tutorial_id=<?php echo $tutRow->tutorial_id; ?>">View</a>)</li>
      </ul>
      <?php
      }

  }
  ?>
  </div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="CollapsiblePanel2" class="CollapsiblePanel">
  <div class="CollapsiblePanelTab" tabindex="0">Tutorials waiting for approval.</div>
  <div class="CollapsiblePanelContent">

    <?php
  if ((isset($_SESSION['log']) && $_SESSION['log']=1)) {
  $getUserData ="select * from tutorials where client_email='".$_SESSION['email']."' AND active=0";
  $getUserDataResulte = $db->query($userTutorialCounts) or die($db->error);

  while($tutRow = $getUserDataResulte -> fetch_object()){
      ?>
      <ul style="list-style-type:circle;">
      <li style="margin-left:20px; font-size:14px; color:#006;"><?php echo $tutRow->tutorial_title; ?>&nbsp;
      (<a style="color:#F00;" href="index.php?learn_id=90&tutorial_id=<?php echo $tutRow->tutorial_id; ?>">Edit</a> 
      &nbsp;- <a style="color:#F00;" href="index.php?learn_id=5&tutorial_id=<?php echo $tutRow->tutorial_id; ?>">View</a>)</li>
    </ul>
      <?php
      }

  }
  ?>

  </div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var CollapsiblePanel1 = new Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel("CollapsiblePanel1");
var CollapsiblePanel2 = new Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel("CollapsiblePanel2");
</script>
</body>
```

What did I do wrong with this so it doesn't do it right?

Comment: What do those `echo` as?

Comment: jprofitt I have mentioned that it echo every thing in my table like it didn't see the code AND active=0

Comment: Don't jump to conclusions... he could have `$_SESSION['email'] = my_sqlcleanfunc($_SESSION['email'])` above that code. Though I really doubt it

Comment: `echo $getUserData;` to make sure there's nothing weird going on.  Maybe some odd characters in `$_SESSION['email']`.

Comment: where does `AND active="1"` get you?

Comment: @YousefAltaf I was wanting to see if your **query** is properly formatted, not the data from the table.

Comment: What is the value of `$_SESSION['email']`? That is to say, what do you get as an output when you execute: `echo $getUserData` AFTER the statement set up?

Comment: I put the whole code there so no doubt around there

Comment: We don't know what `$_SESSION['email']` is storing as its value. In order for us to see it, we need you to `echo $getUserData` and show us that result. Until then there is very little we can do to help you. PLEASE do that and post what it displays.

Comment: Oh I got this <code>select * from tutorials where client_email='admin@admin.com' AND active=0</code> after <code> echo $getUserData </code>

Comment: Since you fetch all fields via `select *` anyway you could simply print the values in question e.g. by placing something like `<?php echo 'debug: '; var_dump($tutRow->client_email, $tutRow->active); ?>` somewhere within the while loop(s).

Comment: btw: `if( ...$_SESSION['log']=1` is missing another `=`

Comment: Thanks VolkerK but this didn't make any changes it's still not working proper any new ideas will be appreciate

Comment: ◦10 HTML Tips for Beginners  (Edit  - View)
debug: 
string 'Admin@admin.com' (length=15) 
string '1' (length=1) 
◦9 Most Common IE Bugs and How to Fix Them   (Edit  - View)
debug: 
string 'admin@admin.com' (length=15) 
string '1' (length=1) 
◦How to Set Up Firefox Sync Between Windows and the iPad  (Edit  - View)
debug: 
string 'admin@admin.com' (length=15) 
string '1' (length=1) 
◦How to Save Firefox 4 Tab Groups Between Sessions  (Edit  - View)
debug: 
string 'admin@admin.com' (length=15) 
string '1' (length=1) 
◦Using the CSS z-index  (Edit  - View)

Comment: this what I got from the debug results

Comment: Thanks everybody for replaying to me and really I am very sorry for this, it was my fault I am calling the wrong MySQL all this time I should call this $getUserData but I was calling something else thanks for you all again and sorry for the miss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the SQL you build to the database:

```
$getUserData ="select * from tutorials where client_email='".$_SESSION['email']."' AND active=1";
$getUserDataResulte = $db->query($userTutorialCounts) or die($db->error);
```

`$getUserData` is not `$userTutorialCounts`

Comment: Cal thanks dear sir I solved the problem and it was my fault forgetting to change this variable to query the ($getUserData) tanks Cal its nice from you to replay to me